# Can I invoke another form 's task

Tags: c#, task

in form1 ,  there are two functions ,  one for a button 's click event

```
    private void bQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sPrefix = tbPrefix.Text.Trim();
        QueryAll(sPrefix);
    }
```

another one is a task

```
    async Task QueryAll(string sPrefix)
    {
    }
```

now I  need invoke form1 's task in form2 certain function ,  such as

```
            string prefix = "abc";

            frm = new form1();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            frm.Dispose();
            frm.QueryAll(sPrefix);
```

I  know this statement

```
frm.QueryAll(sPrefix);
```

can not compile , just to show what I want to do ,  anyone knows how to call this task "QueryAll" ? thanks for your help

Comment: It isn't a task, it's a method. Specifically, a private method.

Comment: why not put this shared function in a separate class rather than tying to a specific form, since it's now used by multiple forms?

Answer (score 2):

it will be task

```
  public Task QueryAll(string sPrefix)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //code here
            var foo = sPrefix;
        });
    }
```

then

```
 frm = new form1();
 frm.QueryAll(sPrefix).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```